# How to call a javascript function from a servlet?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I submit a (jsp) form to a Servlet A. Then I handle some logic which would make the submission either a success or a failure. I use jquery's ajaxForm() function to re-direct the user to a different jsp after the Servlet logic is executed. But before this redirection happens I need to show a javascript notification showing whether the submission was successful or not. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered just storing the response in the user's server-side session, getting the servlet to redirect to the new JSP and getting that new page to display the response as part of its normal content? If you're going to issue a redirect and do a page refresh anyway (so the use of AJAX is moot) then why force the user to click an alert box or whatever when you can flash the alert on the next page? Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `success` callback handler. This will be invoked whenever the servlet has returned a response. You can access the returned response as 1st argument in the callback handler. Easiest way would be to let the servlet return a [JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)) response so that you can access it as a JavaScript object:

```
$('#formId').ajaxForm({ 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (response.error) {
            alert('Something failed: ' + response.error);
        } else {
            alert('Submit was successful.');
            window.location = 'newpage.jsp';
        }
    }
});
```

In the servlet you need to return the response something like as:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
if (submit was not successful) {
    response.getWriter().write("{ error: '" + message + "' }");
} else {
    response.getWriter().write("{ error: false }");
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. But What I need is slightly different from this. I want to show a different message if the backend operation fails. (Failing refers to a user error) 
Any idea?

Comment: I tried this out and it perfectly fits my requirement. A big thank you another time!